# CAD to Feature Class

Tags: python-2.7, esri, cad

```
import arcpy
fc = r'H:\H-ONUS UTILITY DATA GIS\As_Builts\2014\RandolphPoint_Phase2\789-AS-BUILT 8-7-13.dwg\Polyline'
out_gdb = r'H:\H-ONUS UTILITY DATA GIS\As_Builts\2014\RandolphPoint_Phase2\RandolphPoint.gdb.gdb'
field = 'Layer'
values = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, (field))]
uniqueValues = set(Values)

for value in uniqueValues:
    sql = """Layer" = '{0}'""".format(Value)
    name = arcpy.ValidateTableName(value,out_gdb)
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(fc, out_gdb, name, sql)
```

I am trying to convert CAD(dwg) to ArcGIS 10.2.2 Feature Classes using a file geodatase as the workspace.  I was just taught this code at an ESRI conference and of course it worked beautifully for the insturtor.
My error I am getting is "NameError:name'Values' is not defined" however I did define it as values = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, (field))]  I have been working hours on this, it would help out my job considerably.

Answer (score 0):

Python variables are case-sensitive.

You've declared `values` with a lower-case v, but you're referring to it on the next line with an upper-case V.

(Same with `value`/`Value` further down.

Comment: Thank you I didn't catch that, however I just changed and it and still the same error.

Comment: Can you update your post, please? (You might get some help from more competent Python people if you tag it with `python` too :) )

Comment: how do I update it?  I just added the python tag.  This is my first time using the site and I am new to Python, took some ESRI classes but need much more training.

Answer (score 0):

```
import arcpy
fc = r'H:\H-ONUS UTILITY DATA GIS\As_Builts\2014\RandolphPoint_Phase2\789ASBUILT.dwg\Polyline'
out_gdb = r'H:\H-ONUS UTILITY DATA GIS\As_Builts\2014\RandolphPoint_Phase2\RandolphPoint.gdb'
field = 'Layer'
value = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, (field))]
uniquevalues = set(value)

for value in uniquevalues:
    sql = """"Layer" = '{0}'""".format(value)
    name = arcpy.ValidateTableName(value,out_gdb)
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(fc, out_gdb, name, sql)
```

Here is the solution, I had an extra .gdb in the geodatabase path

my word value was values so had to take the s off

and also in my sql statement I was missing a " before the word Layer

If anyone is reading this just change the individual parameters and it works beautifully!

thanks Juffy for responding and trying to help me out

Cartogal